# Normalisation before and after PCA

Tags: machine-learning, pca, matlab, normalization, dimensionality-reduction

Is it valid to normalise a dataset, reduce dimensionality with PCA and then to normalise the reduced dimension data?

Assuming this is performed on training data, should the same PCA coefficients be used to reduce the dimension of the test data? Should the same max and min normalisation values be used for the test and training data?

I have included a simplified example of the Matlab code I am using which may describe I said better:

```
%%// Prepare Training Data


%// Normalise training data
mindata=min(TRAINDATA); maxdata=max(TRAINDATA);
TRAINDATA = ((TRAINDATA-repmat(mindata,[size(TRAINDATA,1),1]))./ ...
            (repmat(maxdata,[size(TRAINDATA,1),1])-repmat(mindata,[size(TRAINDATA,1),1])) - 0.5 ) *2;

%// Perform PCA
mTRAINDATA = mean(mean(TRAINDATA));
TRAINDATA = TRAINDATA - mTRAINDATA;
[Cpca,~,~,~,~]=princomp(TRAINDATA,'econ');
EigenRange = 1:2;
Cpca = Cpca(:,EigenRange);
TRAINDATA = TRAINDATA*Cpca;
TRAINDATA = TRAINDATA + mTRAINDATA;

%// Normalise training data second time
mindata2=min(TRAINDATA); maxdata2=max(TRAINDATA);
TRAINDATA = ((TRAINDATA-repmat(mindata2,[size(TRAINDATA,1),1]))./ ...
            (repmat(maxdata2,[size(TRAINDATA,1),1])-repmat(mindata2,[size(TRAINDATA,1),1])) - 0.5 ) *2;



%%// Prepare Test Data

%// Normalise using first normalisation values from training data
TESTDATA = ((TESTDATA-repmat(mindata,[size(TESTDATA,1),1]))./(repmat(maxdata,[size(TESTDATA,1),1])-repmat(mindata,[size(TESTDATA,1),1])) - 0.5 ) *2;

%// Perform PCA
mTESTDATA = mean(mean(TESTDATA));
TESTDATA = TESTDATA - mTESTDATA;
TESTDATA = TESTDATA*Cpca;
TESTDATA = TESTDATA + mTRAINDATA;

%// Normalise using second normalisation values from training data
TESTDATA = ((TESTDATA-repmat(mindata2,[size(TESTDATA,1),1]))./ ...
           (repmat(maxdata2,[size(TESTDATA,1),1])-repmat(mindata2,[size(TESTDATA,1),1])) - 0.5 ) *2;
```

Comment: Why do you compute `mean(mean(TRAINDATA))`? This is a global average over all features and all samples, what's the point of subtracting it? This is not centering your data, because centering implies subtracting means of each feature.

Comment: Also, what exactly is your "normalization"? You subtract the `min`, then divide by `max-min`, then subtract 0.5, then multiply by 2 -- is that correct? So you want all the values to be between -1 and 1?

Comment: I should mention I am adapting someone else's work and the reason I have posted here is I am a little sceptical of this section. I do in fact want all values to lie between -1 and 1 so I am happy with that.  I am not entirely sure about the `mean(mean(TRAINDATA))? ` part so I will look into that. I am mostly enquiring is the PCA applied correctly and is it ok to normalise a second time.  Thank, Michael.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with normalizing twice. Regarding training and testing data, yes, you should normalize and transform the testing data  using only the parameters estimated on the training data.